# What to say when answering the phone

Tags: set-phrases, politeness

I'm often unsure what to say when answering the telephone when I am the customer; people usually say their name and then wait for me to say something before stating their business. I'm guessing there is a set phrase that people usually say at that point.

Usually it goes like:

- **Me:** はい、XXです。
- **Them:** XX社のXXXと申します。
- **Me:** お世話になってます。 ← *What I'm unsure about*

Is this appropriate to say as a customer? What if I've never spoken to them before? What else could I say here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not expecting their call, then one does wonder what exactly the 世話 could be that made them call you. If it's a company where you are a customer, I would probably wait to hear more, so

- *Me.* はい、◯◯です。
- *Them.* ◯◯社の◯◯と申します。
- *Me.* はい。

If you want a firmer handle on the conversation, you can also ask

- *Me.* どういったご用件ですか。

If in the end you did benefit from their call (i.e. it wasn't just a sales call, but they helped you fix something, set something in order, etc.), you can always say something nice later.

- *Me.* お世話様でした。 (*or* よろしくお願いします。 *or* ご苦労様でした。)

(Note that お世話様でした is **not** a different way of saying お世話になっています. The former is said from "above" to "below", the latter is said from "below" to "above".)

Comment: Thanks, I have just said はい before as in your example and it seemed a little awkward like they were waiting for something more, maybe it's just my imagination though..

Answer (score 2):

If you are a customer I wouldn't care too much. `お世話になってます` would be a good choice. `あ、どうも` or even `はい` would work (albeit less polite, but as a customer you don't need to be polite). If you want to ask why they called you can say `何のお電話でしょう？` or `どうしました？`.